# Running a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PS and have been given a script to run.  The first thing I do is type in `c:\powershell\ir.ps1`.  This seems to work.  Then after defining my clients directory I am supposed to be able to just type in functions such as `ir-n`.  This worked at the person's desk that showed me how to do it, but I get the following error:

```
The term 'ir-n' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ ir-n <<<<
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ir-n:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there something simple I can do to get it to run?  I see the function in the `ir.ps1` file so I know it is there.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are running the `ir.ps1` script when you should be sourcing it.  I'm guessing that the `ir.ps1` file is defining a function named `ir-n`.  In that case running the script will not define the function in the script's context but not the command window.  You need to source the script to get it to persist in the command window.

Try running the following

```
PS$> . c:\powershell\ir.ps1
```

After running this then try `ir-n`.

Comment: you guys and this forum is awesome... it worked.  i will see if i can get it done now if not i will be back.  thanks!

Comment: I can't believe you noted that the answer is great and haven't accepted it yet. I am sure it is just a simple oversight. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to `dot source` the script which will leave the functions it defines available in the global scope e.g.:

```
PS> . c:\powershell\ir.ps1
```